# How to collect the JWT Token and store it in Amplify Flutter

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, dart, jwt, aws-amplify

I am trying to build a web-app using Flutter, Dart and AWS Amplify. I have a simple boilerplate code that the documentation provides. I want to get JWT Token from a user who is currently logged into my app using the sign-in/sign-up authentication service that I have setup using Cognito.

Below is my code:

```
import 'package:amplify_auth_cognito/amplify_auth_cognito.dart';
import 'package:amplify_authenticator/amplify_authenticator.dart';
import 'package:amplify_flutter/amplify_flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'amplifyconfiguration.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _configureAmplify();
  }

  void _configureAmplify() async {
    try {
      await Amplify.addPlugin(AmplifyAuthCognito());
      await Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
      safePrint('Successfully configured');
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      safePrint('Error configuring Amplify: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> signOutCurrentUser() async {
    final result = await Amplify.Auth.signOut();
    if (result is CognitoCompleteSignOut) {
      print('Sign out completed successfully');
    } else if (result is CognitoFailedSignOut) {
      print('Error signing user out: ${result.exception.message}');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Authenticator(
      initialStep: AuthenticatorStep.signIn,
      child: MaterialApp(
        builder: Authenticator.builder(),
        home: const Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: Text('You are logged in!'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I did try the code provided in the below documentation:

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/access_credentials/q/platform/flutter/

But I still cannot get the jwt token(access token) required.

My ultimate aim is to use this token to hit some of the API endpoints that I have created. The above does not have any token related code as I removed it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You can collect JWT token (Access token) like this.

```
Future<void> fetchCognitoAuthSession() async {
  try {
    final cognitoPlugin = 
         Amplify.Auth.getPlugin(AmplifyAuthCognito.pluginKey);
    final result = await cognitoPlugin.fetchAuthSession();
    final identityId = result.identityIdResult.value;
    final accessToken = 
         session.userPoolTokensResult.value.accessToken.toJson();
    safePrint("Current user's access token: $accessToken");
    safePrint("Current user's identity ID: $identityId");
  } on AuthException catch (e) {
    safePrint('Error retrieving auth session: ${e.message}');
  }
}
```